# How can I make xubuntu ignore DisplayPort monitor being turned off?

Tags: xubuntu, monitor, displayport

I have a desktop machine (Dell T5600) with an Nvidia graphics card (Quadro 2000), and two monitors (Dell 24"), and I'm running xubuntu 14.04. If I switch off a monitor connected with DisplayPort, xubuntu detects the monitor being removed, and rearranges my desktop. On switching it back on, I have to reconfigure my desktop setup (extented desktop on two monitors). If I switch off a monitor connected to DVI, this does not happen, and when I switch it back on, everything is at it was.

How can I make xubuntu ignore the monitor being turned off, and keep everything the way it was when I turn it back on?

Answer (score 1):

Not really the most elegant solution, but I managed to solve my immediate problem by connecting the monitor via a DisplayPort-to-DVI adapter. When using this adapter, it seems the computer can't tell whether the monitor is on or off, and thus it doesn't reconfigure anything when I turn off the monitor.

I'd still like to know how to solve this problem in software, though.